# Sorting the first elements of a 2D array based on values provided in the array to be sorted

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I am learning the Java language and I have this task to sort movies based on their popularity, the info being retrieved from a database.

So far I have the following 2D array of type String[20][6]. The 20 stands for the number of String[] arrays inside, which represent movies, while the 6 corresponds to each movie's variables, such as:

```
[0] - path of image for the movie; 
[1] - overview of the movie;
[2] - release date of the movie;
[3] - title of the movie;
[4] - popularity (expressed in a double format) of the movie;
[5] - average rating (expressed in a double format) of the movie.
```

I want to make it so that the sequence of movies [20] is so that the popularity is in a descending order, while not altering the data. I have read about comparators and such, only to get stuck and lost trying to figure out how to correctly apply them.

The reason behind this is that I am populating a gridView with images of the most popular movies, and I want to implement a function to sort these movies either by popularity, or by average votes (currently they are being populated in the sequence that the database provides).

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the data structure to be something like `List<Movie>` so that a better sorting algorithm can be easily applied. In that case, you could have something like

```
Collections.sort(movies, new PopularityComparator());
```

which uses java's native (efficient) sorting algorithm. `PopularityComparator` could be something like this (assuming `getPopularity()` returns a `Double`)

```
public class PopularityComparator implements Comparator<Movie> {
@Override
public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
    return Double.compare(m2.getPopularity(), m1.getPopularity());
}
}
```

But strictly speaking about the question, I think the code below should work for you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; i < movies.length; j++) {
            if (Double.compare(Double.parseDouble(movies[i][4]), Double.parseDouble(movies[j][4])) >= 0) {
                //swap movies[i] and movies[j]
                String[] temp = movies[i];
                movies[i] = movies[j];
                movies[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answers the question and also explains good practices. Nice answer!

Comment: First of all thank you for answering so quicky, your method indeed did the trick for me, and now everything runs smoothly. Rating this as the correct answer! 

(You also made comparators look easier :) )

Comment: @Mikas happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
            if(movies[i][4]>movies[j][4]){
                // swap movies[i] & movies[j] 
            }
        }
    }
```

Use this code.Hope help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering on such short notice! I tried implementing your code, but sorting 2 times in a row messed things up somehow, don't know on whose head that is. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to work with Objects in java (when i look at the code i can more easily figure out what i wanted to do) and than if you have to convert them into multi-dimensional string array. Look at the two solutions, first is what you want and the second i what i suggest. Hope it helps you.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 *
 * @author Adrian Stefanovski
 */
public class StackOverflow {

    public static String[][] sorting_array = new String[20][6];
    public static int max_popularity = 10;
    public static int max_rating = 10;
    public static ArrayList<MovieSomething> sorting_array_list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Solution 1
        populate_array();
        print_not_sorted_array();
        sort_array();
        print_sorted_array();
        //Solution 2
        populate_array(); //Use diferent values
        populate_array_list();
        print_not_sorted_array_list();
        sort_array_list();
        print_sorted_array_list();
        to_multi_d_string_array();
    }

    public static void populate_array() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            sorting_array[i][0] = "path " + i;
            sorting_array[i][1] = "overview  " + i;
            sorting_array[i][2] = "release date " + i;
            sorting_array[i][3] = "title " + i;
            sorting_array[i][4] = String.valueOf(Math.random() * max_popularity); //popularity  
            sorting_array[i][5] = String.valueOf(Math.random() * max_rating); //average rating
        }
    }

    public static void print_not_sorted_array() {
        System.out.println("Without sorting array");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(sorting_array[i][0] + " " + sorting_array[i][1] + " " + sorting_array[i][2] + " " + sorting_array[i][3] + " " + sorting_array[i][4] + " " + sorting_array[i][5]);
        }
    }

    public static void sort_array() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 20; j++) {
                if (Double.valueOf(sorting_array[i][4]) < Double.valueOf(sorting_array[j][4])) {
                    rotate_members(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void rotate_members(int i, int j) {
        String temp_column_0 = sorting_array[i][0];
        String temp_column_1 = sorting_array[i][1];
        String temp_column_2 = sorting_array[i][2];
        String temp_column_3 = sorting_array[i][3];
        String temp_column_4 = sorting_array[i][4];
        String temp_column_5 = sorting_array[i][5];
        sorting_array[i][0] = sorting_array[j][0];
        sorting_array[i][1] = sorting_array[j][1];
        sorting_array[i][2] = sorting_array[j][2];
        sorting_array[i][3] = sorting_array[j][3];
        sorting_array[i][4] = sorting_array[j][4];
        sorting_array[i][5] = sorting_array[j][5];
        sorting_array[j][0] = temp_column_0;
        sorting_array[j][1] = temp_column_1;
        sorting_array[j][2] = temp_column_2;
        sorting_array[j][3] = temp_column_3;
        sorting_array[j][4] = temp_column_4;
        sorting_array[j][5] = temp_column_5;
    }

    public static void print_sorted_array() {
        System.out.println("With sorting array");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(sorting_array[i][0] + " " + sorting_array[i][1] + " " + sorting_array[i][2] + " " + sorting_array[i][3] + " " + sorting_array[i][4] + " " + sorting_array[i][5]);
        }
    }

    public static void populate_array_list() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            sorting_array_list.add(new MovieSomething(sorting_array[i][0], sorting_array[i][1], sorting_array[i][2], sorting_array[i][3], Double.valueOf(sorting_array[i][4]), Double.valueOf(sorting_array[i][5])));
        }
    }

    public static void print_not_sorted_array_list() {
        System.out.println("Without sorting array list");
        sorting_array_list.stream().forEach((movie) -> {
            System.out.println(movie.toString());
        });
    }

    public static void sort_array_list() {
        Collections.sort(sorting_array_list, new Comparator<MovieSomething>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MovieSomething fruit2, MovieSomething fruit1) {
                if (fruit1.popularity > fruit2.popularity) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        );
    }

    public static void print_sorted_array_list() {
        System.out.println("With sorting array list");
        sorting_array_list.stream().forEach((movie) -> {
            System.out.println(movie.toString());
        });
    }

    public static void to_multi_d_string_array() {
        int i = 0;
        for (MovieSomething movie : sorting_array_list) {
            sorting_array[i][0] = movie.path;
            sorting_array[i][1] = movie.overview;
            sorting_array[i][2] = movie.release_date;
            sorting_array[i][3] = movie.title;
            sorting_array[i][4] = String.valueOf(movie.popularity);
            sorting_array[i][5] = String.valueOf(movie.average_rating);
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    public static class MovieSomething {

        public final String path;
        public final String overview;
        public final String release_date;
        public final String title;
        public final double popularity;
        public final double average_rating;

        public MovieSomething(String path, String overview, String release_date, String title, double popularity, double average_rating) {
            this.path = path;
            this.overview = overview;
            this.release_date = release_date;
            this.title = title;
            this.popularity = popularity;
            this.average_rating = average_rating;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MovieSomething{" + "path=" + path + ", overview=" + overview + ", release_date=" + release_date + ", title=" + title + ", popularity=" + popularity + ", average_rating=" + average_rating + '}';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats a looot of code for such a measly operation in my eyes :D I appreciate the effort tremendously, but I'll need some time until i can sort out everything that you wrote, since I do not like to use code I can't properly understand or which confuses me.

Comment: I can shorten 90% of it and post it tomorrow, make it one functions. I didn't know what would you need. Should the entry parameter and the return value be String[][] ?

Comment: Yes, although another answer already worked for me, feel free to express your creativity!

Comment: It will be similar so I don't wanna spam the forum. :)